# CSS3 Transitions in Stylus - how to degrade for IE9

Tags: jquery, css, coffeescript, css-transitions, stylus

So, I have an img tag in .image-wrapper I want to pan down on hover.  Pretty basic use of CSS3 transition - based on here: http://designshack.net/articles/css/joshuajohnson-2/

Here's my stylus code:

```
// Portfolio

.portfolio-wide
  .image-wrapper
    height 300px
    overflow hidden

.portfolio-wide
  .image-wrapper img
    width 100%
    margin-top 0px
    transition all 10s ease


.portfolio-wide
  .image-wrapper:hover img
    margin-top -100%
```

Stylus and Nib turn this into CSS with all the browser specific stuff.

My problem is IE<10 sucks and instead of panning down, it jumps right down - which looks broken.  This feature isn't that important so I just want to disable it on IE<10.

How do I do that in Stylus?  Seems like a pretty common thing but I couldn't find an example or documentation.

Suggestions?  I tried some jQuery CoffeeScript to add/remove the style on page load, but it didn't work.

```
$(document).ready ->

  # Like I don't have better things to do IE...
  # determine if the browser supports transition
  thisStyle = document.body.style
  supportsTransition = true
  (thisStyle.WebkitTransition !== undefined || thisStyle.MozTransition !== undefined || thisStyle.OTransition !== undefined || thisStyle.transition !== undefined)

  alert supportsTransition

  # assign jQuery transition if the browser doesn't support
  $if ( supportsTransition )
    alert "here"
    $(".portfolio-wide .image-wrapper:hover img").css('margin-top', '-100%')
```

The alerts were happening at the right time, but I didn't see the right effect in the code.  In the code above, the margin-top style wasn't added, so the transition didn't happen.  I tried .css('margin-top', '0px') to remove on !supportsTranstion, but it didn't work.

Anyways, It's a boondoggle on IE and I just want to disable it.  Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is a bit old, but here's two solutions :

**• Easy and clean solution :** Use Modernizr (http://modernizr.com/). It'll add classes to html tag for each property supported in your browser (ex : csstransitions). Then, with Stylus (or any other stylesheet document) you can easily target any element this way :

```
html.csstransitions
    .portfolio-wide
        .image-wrapper img
            transition all 10s ease
```

**• Heavy solution :** Use jQuery transit (http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/). It works the same way as animate() but with css3 transition. As a benefit, you can always fallback to animate() when transition is not supported :

```
if (!$.support.transition) {
    $.fn.transition = $.fn.animate;
}
```

Comment: Nice, I haven't tried this, but it makes sense from here.  I'll check it out.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome :) As a notice, you can make custom build of Modernizr if you only need to detect one or two features… (reducing drastically this lib size)